# How to hook a function at runtime

Tags: c, windows, nasm

I have the following code，This code comes from "https://blog.securehat.co.uk/process-injection/manually-implementing-inline-function-hooking"，I modified one to hook up my own function，But there was an error running.

```c
#include <Windows.h>

#include <stdio.h>

typedef int(__stdcall* tdOrigFunction)(int name);
tdOrigFunction testFunctionATrampoline;

int __stdcall HookedTestFunction(int name)
{
    printf("HookedMessageBox\n");
    testFunctionATrampoline(name);
    return 2;
}

int Error(const char* msg) {
    printf("%s (%u)", msg, GetLastError());
    return 1;
}
int testFunction(int name) {
    printf("testFunction");
    printf("testFunction");
    printf("testFunction");
    printf("testFunction");
    printf("testFunction");
    printf("testFunction%d",name);
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    BYTE* origFunctionAddress = NULL;
    BYTE* trampolineAddress = NULL;



    origFunctionAddress = testFunction;
    HANDLE hProcess = GetCurrentProcess();

    BYTE buffer[128] = { 0 };

    SIZE_T nSize = sizeof(buffer);
    SIZE_T bytesRead; 
    BOOL result = ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, origFunctionAddress, buffer, nSize, &bytesRead);

    int offset = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        offset |= (buffer[1 + i] << (i * 8));
    }
    origFunctionAddress = origFunctionAddress + offset + 5;

    trampolineAddress = (BYTE*)VirtualAlloc(NULL, 20, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    if (trampolineAddress == NULL) {
        Error("Failed to allocate memory for trampoline");
    }

    int numOfBytesToCopy = 5;
    char trampoline[10] = { 0 };

    memcpy_s(trampoline, numOfBytesToCopy, origFunctionAddress, 5);


    *(DWORD*)(trampoline + numOfBytesToCopy) = 0xE9;


    uintptr_t jumpAddress = (BYTE*)origFunctionAddress - trampolineAddress - numOfBytesToCopy;


    *(uintptr_t*)((uintptr_t)trampoline + numOfBytesToCopy + 1) = jumpAddress;

    if (!WriteProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), trampolineAddress, trampoline, sizeof(trampoline), NULL)) {
        return Error("Error while writing process memory to trampoline");
    }


    DWORD oldProtectVal;
    VirtualProtect(origFunctionAddress, 6, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProtectVal);

    *(BYTE*)origFunctionAddress = 0xE9;


    intptr_t hookAddress = (intptr_t)((CHAR*)HookedTestFunction - (intptr_t)origFunctionAddress) - 5;


    *(intptr_t*)((intptr_t)origFunctionAddress + 1) = hookAddress;


    VirtualProtect(origFunctionAddress, 6, oldProtectVal, &oldProtectVal);


    testFunctionATrampoline = (tdOrigFunction)trampolineAddress;

    testFunction(1);

    return 0;
}
```

I can't find any relevant hook methods, most of them are for DLLs, not my requirements

Comment: The calculation should be relative to the address of HookedTestFunction rather than origFunctionAddress. You should calculate the offset between HookedTestFunction and origFunctionAddress and use that to set the jump address.

Comment: I don't quite understand assembly. Could you take a few minutes to help me make the necessary modifications? Thank you very much。